# Travel on last day of Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas, layovers

I have a Schengen visa valid from 10th Oct to 29th Oct with 5 days duration of stay. I will be reaching Copenhagen on 10th Oct and returning on 14th Oct, my return flight to India leaves Copenhagen at 15:45 on 14th Oct, so I am not staying more than 5 days in Schengen states, However, in this return flight I have a 9h layover at Doha (22:45 on 14th to 8:05 on 15th) and I will be reaching India at 14:20 on 15th. Will I face any issues at Doha airport OR at Mumbai airport? I don't see any concerns, but just trying to get opinions :)

Comment: Do you plan to leave the secured international area at Doha ? Just for confirmation, do you hold an Indian passport?

Comment: Why would Doha or India care that you are no longer authorized to be in the Schengen area?  You will no longer be in the Schengen area at that point, and you will have left before the end of your period of authorized stay.

Comment: thanks for your comments :). i am not planning to go out of the Doha airport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your visa should be valid only till you leave the Schengen passport control. The layovers, outside the Schengen area after this won't be a problem anyway.

Comment: But that’s cutting it close if there are any issues (delays, flight cancellations…) which would make OP miss their intended flight.